# Unable to write to text files when creating program to .MSI file Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have a program which stores different things such as reports, products etc. and relys heavily on reading and writing to text files.

I have used Visual Studio Installer to turn the program into a .MSI file using the set up wizard. When asked if there are any extra files, I did add all the text files.

However, I cannot write to them. I seem to be able to read them, however if I try to delete anything in the files, or add something to them I get accessed denied.

I went through all the text files that had been installed, and changed them so the user had full permissions, however this does not seem to have helped.

Does anyone have any idea why this may have happened?

Thanks

Lucy

Answer (score 0):

You are probably storing those files in Program Files folder, i.e. where the application is installed. This folder requires admin rights to write inthere.

Read more about the correct way and [locations where to store user and application data](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/).